# FFmpeg Creating Visulization from mp3 ubunutu + PHP

Tags: video, ffmpeg, php, mp3

I am creating a script that will create a video avectorscope video with ffmpeg from an mp3. I keep getting the following error in my log files while running the following code:

**PHP**

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ../a5ca0b5894324f8bb54bb9fffad29d1e/tagged/d13c24d9be.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]avectorscope=s=1280x720,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4');
```

**Error in log file:**

```
Input #0, mp3, from '../a5ca0b5894324f8bb54bb9fffad29d1e/tagged/d13c24d9be.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
  Duration: 00:03:30.21, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.48
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x286d960] No such filter: ''
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
sh: 2: [0:a]avectorscope=s=1280x720,format=yuv420p[v]: not found
sh: 3: -map: not found
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP user but it appears that each broken line is being interpreted as an individual command. Lazy fix is to make the command one line.

Comment: Thanks LongNeckbeard, that fixed the problem! I appreciate you always helping out with FFmpeg, anytime I see a ffmpeg post you usually have the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LongNeckbeard for the help! If you get this error you just have to remove the broken lines:

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ../a5ca0b5894324f8bb54bb9fffad29d1e/tagged/d13c24d9be.mp3 -filter_complex \ "[0:a]avectorscope=s=1280x720,format=yuv420p[v]" \-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4');
```

Comment: You can remove the backslashes.